# Multiple SimpleMembership Providers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

Is it possible to use multiple simple membership providers? and if it is possible, how can I switch between them in my asp.net mvc application?

UPDATE:

I tried to define two simple membership providers in webconfig like this:

```
<membership defaultProvider="simple">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="simple" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
    <add name="simple2" connectionStringName="Membership" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

and then tried to call validate user for simple2 membership provider like this:

```
Membership.Providers["simple2"].ValidateUser(username, password);
```

but since the websecurity initializedatabaseconnection method can be called only once, I can't initialize the other databese, and can not run methods for it.

Any Ideas?

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: There are two databeses that contain membership data. I want to use one of them to only Login actions, and use the other one to create user and account actions, and at the same time I want to use SimpleMembership(WebSecurity) Methods for these actions.